# Powershell Running MSTest.exe with multiple tests - how to output only failed tests?

Tags: .net, powershell, testing, automated-tests, mstest

I have a string of all the tests I want to run with `MSTest.exe`, and I want to output only if there are errors, failed tests and perhaps warnings.

A part of the Powershell script (the `...` stands for many more `/testcontainer:Test....dll`).

```
# sb is a string builder
$sb = "C:\...\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:Test....dll ...  /testcontainer:Test...dll 

cmd.exe /c $sb.ToString()
```

Currently it outputs everything (A lot of "Test passed" for example - which I don't need to see).

I tried looking in the [MSTest command line options docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx) but couldn't find any.

How can I output only the important stuff?

Edit: I'm open to change the testing environment if this feature exists there.

Comment: You can try to use [usestderr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx#usestderr) to forward failed tests to different stream. Then, you can use `-ErrorVariable` switch to get them.

Comment: Spit it out in a results file and parse the [results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx#resultsfile)